# Can I have separate shipping charges for different countries in open cart?

Tags: php, opencart

I need separate shipping charges for different countries, is it possible to do in open-cart, How can I change in shipping pages?

Example

- Canada, Mexico, Alaska - ships for $9.99`
- Hawaii & International - ships for $19.99

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done.

Check out http://www.18aproductions.co.uk/news/view/how-to-get-different-shipping-rates-on-your-opencart-shop

Summary:
Use weight based shipping even if your shipping cost don't depend on weight.
The weight based shipping module allows for different zones. 
Just enter an extremely high weight limit to cover all weights with one shipping rate.

Answer (score 0):

There are extensions available in the extension store that handle this. In particular you want to be looking for flat rate geo zone based shipping

Answer (score 0):

You need first to set up each of your shipping areas as a Geo Zone.

The included flat rate shipping module matches one Geo Zone.

It is not (currently) possible to add multiple instances of a module within OpenCart.

As a result, similar modules that allow settings for multiple geo zones have sprung up on the extension store.

You could write your own module, but another (fiddly but free) option is to clone the flat.php files (or relevant shipping module) for each additional GeoZone.

The logic is in catalog\model\shipping; admin controls are in admin\controller\shipping and admin\view\template\shipping. In all these folders you need to duplicate the original file and give it the same new filename (eg flat2, flat3) in each. There's also language in catalog\language\english\shipping and admin\language\english\shipping, but you could use the same language files for all.

You must then edit each to amend the class names (eg change the Free part in ModelShippingFree, ControllerShippingFree to match your Free2).

Then you can go into Admin and set each to a different Geo Zone.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Admin panel -> User Administration -> Extension -> Shipping - Here you can see the geo based shipping price.